# Solution set of $f(g(x)) < 3g(f(x))$

Tags: functions

Assume we have $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 2^x.$ Than, let the solution set of $$f(g(x)) < 3 \cdot g(f(x))$$ be $a < x < b.$ Find the greatest integer not greater than $b - a.$

---

We can substitute in using the given functions. We get the inequality $$2^{x^2} < 3 \cdot 2^{2x}.$$ However, I'm not sure how to apply log from this point on. Can someone give me a hint as to how to apply log?

Comment: $f(g(x))=f(2^x)=(2^x)^2=2^{2x}$, so you have got $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ interchanged in the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inequality is supposed to be $$g(f(x)) < 3f(g(x))$$ because otherwise, $2^{2x} < 3\cdot 2^{x^2}$ is true for all real $x$.

Take log base two of both sides:

$$\log_2(2^{x^2}) < \log_2(3\cdot 2^{2x})$$

$$x^2 < \log_2 3 + \log_2 2^{2x} = \log_2 3 + 2x$$

$$x^2-2x < \log_2 3$$

$$(x-1)^2 < 1+\log_2 3$$

$$1-\sqrt{1+\log_2 3} < x < 1+\sqrt{1+\log_2 3}$$

Finally, you have:

$$\left\lfloor 2\sqrt{1+\log_2 3} \right\rfloor = 3$$